# Is there a limit on how many databases Azure Sql Server (PaaS) can have? And/Or is there a size limit on how much data an Azure Sql Server can hold?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Is there a limit on how many databases Azure Sql Server (PaaS) can have?

And/Or is there a size limit on how much data an Azure Sql Server(PaaS) can hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a limit on how many databases Azure Sql Server (PaaS) can
>   have?

About SQL Database servers per subscription, **default** limit is **6**, the maximum limit is 150.

> And/Or is there a size limit on how much data an Azure Sql
>   Server(PaaS) can hold?

Different service tier have difference performance, more information about the performance please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits).
For example:

[image]

---

Update:

Here is the screenshot about DTU, please check it:

[image]

---

**Update2:**

we can create support ticket to increase DTU quota, the max quota is **99000**.

When you try to increase the quota, the new quota(DTU) value must be **between 54005 and 99000**.
[image]

Hope this helps:)

Comment: I understand the limit for servers per subscription. But how many Azure Single Databases can a Azure Sql Server hold?

Comment: A server is really just a logical construct that gives databases a name (and a firewall, auditing, threat detection).  AFAIK there isn't really a limit since resources are associated with a DB itself, and not the server

Comment: @AndrewTaylor There is no limit about how many Azure single databases can a Azure SQL server hold. for example, SQL Server size is S1, the max DTU is 20, if your database need DTU is 10, we can create 2 databases in that SQL server. just should consider for SQL performance:)

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT So on my Azure Sql Logical Server I see a DTU quota of 54000. Is that the limit on how many single databases I can have? If so, is that the hard limit or can it be extended and how far can it be extended.

Comment: @AndrewTaylor No limit on how many single databases you can have.  we can't expand it.

Comment: Just to confirm you can't expand the DTU quota of the logical server which is currently at 54000?

Comment: @AndrewTaylor we can create [a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to increase the quota.

Comment: @AndrewTaylor please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I appreciate all the help you've given. You have been very helpful. I believe I'm real close to my answer. If i create a support ticket, is there a limit to how high you can increase my logical server DTU quota to or is it limitless? If there is a limit, what is that limit?

Comment: @AndrewTaylor sorry for my misunderstand, the DTU quota 54000 not for SQL database, it the limit of SQL data warehouse. The max DTUs is Premium RS service tier P15, it is 4000 per sql server. if you feel 4000 is not enough, maybe we can deploy another SQL server, also we can use sql servers to create a elastic database pool, I think that is big enough:)

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I'm still referring to the sql server when I'm talking about the 54000 quota. When you create a SQL Database for the first time they make you assign it to a server or create a server. When you click on that server dashboard they present you with a quota. Mine being at 54000 DTU currently. I'm assuming that quota represents the total about of DTUs allowed on that logical server. So I can have as many DBs on that server as long the total DTU doesn't surpass the quota. My question is, if all what I just said is true, can the logical server DTU quota be increased? If yes, how high?

Comment: @AndrewTaylor The max quota is 99000, please check my answer, thanks:)